# Add many rows at once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I'm just starting out with WPF and MVVM framework. I have a Window with telerik `RadGridView` and I would like to add data from multipul rows in the same time. Has anyone got any advice or examples ,I've tried numerous ways but none seem to work out.

Thank you

My ViewModel

```
private IList<Ligne> _CurrentLigne;
public IList<Ligne> CurrentLigne
{
    get { return _CurrentLigne; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentLigne= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLigne");
    }
}

var _ligne = Currentligne as Ligne;

foreach (Ligne ligne in CurrentLigne)
{
    if (Currentligne!= null)    
    _ligneBLL.InsetLigne(ligne);
}
```

My View

```
<telerik:RadGridView  x:Name="GridView"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListeLigne}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLigne, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple" >
```

Comment: Usually I use `.AddRange()` to add multiple items to a list at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This !!

```
foreach (Ligne ligne in ListLigne) 
 {
   var _ligne = ligne as Ligne;   
   _ligneBLL.InsetLigne(ligne); 
 }
```

Comment: Please add explanation for your answer so the OP can better understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN so that you can get a better idea on data binding. For now, I can give you a few tips. Firstly, in WPF, your property should really have used an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Ligne> _ListeLigne = new ObservableCollection<Ligne>();
public ObservableCollection<Ligne> ListeLigne
{
    get { return _ListeLigne; }
    set
    {
        _ListeLigne = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ListeLigne");
    }
}
```

Then your selected item like this:

```
private Ligne _CurrentLigne = new Ligne();
public Ligne CurrentLigne
{
    get { return _CurrentLigne; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentLigne= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLigne");
    }
}
```

With properties like this, your XAML would be fine. Lastly, to add your items, you simply do this:

```
ListeLigne = new ObservableCollection<Ligne>(SomeMethodGettingYourData());
```

Or just...:

```
ListeLigne = SomeMethodGettingYourData();
```

... if your data access method returns an `ObservableCollection<Ligne>`. If you want to select a particular element in the UI, then you must select an actual item from the data bound collection, but you can do that easily using `LinQ`.

```
using System.Linq;

CurrentLigne = ListeLigne.First(l => l.SomeLigneProperty == someValue);
```

Or just:

```
CurrentLigne = ListeLigne.ElementAt(someValidIndexInCollection);
```

---

Oh... and I've got one other tip for you. In your code:

```
foreach (Ligne ligne in CurrentLigne)
{
    if (Currentligne!= null)    // this is a pointless if condition
    _ligneBLL.InsetLigne(ligne);
}
```

The above `if` condition is pointless because the program execution will never enter the `foreach` loop if the collection is `null`.

Comment: can I bind a list to SelectedItem @sheridan because I want to add many rows in the same time

Comment: The selected item can only be an actual item from the data bound collection. So you can only use an `IList` as the selected item if each item in the data bound collection is an `IList`.

Comment: can you please explain more @sheridan

Comment: Perhaps I should quit my job and become your personal tutor for free? This website is *not* here to teach users new languages, or give tutorials... [it is here to help developers with specific programming problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You need to read some online tutorials and *many* pages from MSDN instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a BindingList. It is the list I always use, but remember you will need to post your notifyChange events.